# Using the same custom table-view multiple times in one window?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have created a table view in a nib that I want to use twice in the same window. The table view has its own controller, and I want to connect various parts as outlets. I can do that in the tableview's nib by setting the file owner to the view controller. However, how can I then get this tableview into the parent window?

It looks as if I can't do it through the interface builder?

So I have begun by creating two instance variables in the window controller for the two controllers. I assume I have to do this programmatically? How do I set the locations of each view correctly? Are there any side-effects from doing this? I am doing the window layout for everything else within the interface builder itself. I just can't see this working, however.

I also tried adding in a couple of scrollviews in the window where the table views would go. I thought perhaps then I could hook the scrollview up as an outlet and add them this way. At least then everything would be laid out correctly. This also doesn't seem to work though.

Comment: same window? means you are not using viewcontrollers?

Comment: @LithuT.V I have a window that I want to have two custom views in it as subviews. Of course I am using view controllers.